# Binding ng-model to ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to bind ng-model dynamically with ng-repeat, but it doesn't seem to work. input.placeholder and input.fa both work as expected, but I can't seem to bind ng-model to anything as it gives me an error.

The relevant HTML

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="input in accountInfo">
   <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
     <input type="text" placeholder="{{input.placeholder}}" ng-model="{{input.model}}"/>
     <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa {{input.fa}}"></i></div>
   </div>
</li>
```

My accountInfo array of objects.

```
$scope.accountInfo = [
  {
    model: 'user.fullName',
    placeholder: 'Full Name',
    fa: 'fa-user',
  },
  {
    model: 'user.email',
    placeholder: 'Email Address',
    fa: 'fa-envelope',
  },
  {
    model: 'user.password',
    placeholder: 'Password',
    fa: 'fa-key',
  },
  {
    model: 'user.phone',
    placeholder: 'Phone Number',
    fa: 'fa-phone',
  },
];
```

The error i get

[error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Binput.model%7D%7D&p4=%7Binput.model%7D%7D)

Please help

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` is not interpolated; you shouldn't wrap it in `{{`. So,

```
<input ... ng-model="input.model">
```

should work fine.

---

Edit: Sorry, I didn't see that you were trying to dynamically set the ng-model -- my apologies.

The easiest solution would be to use references in the `accountInfo`, if `user` is available in that scope:

```
    $scope.accountInfo = [{
        model: user.fullName,
        placeholder: 'Full Name',
        ...
```

Otherwise, you can declare an object on the `$scope` and manually link it to the models:

```
// ... some place without access to `user`
$scope.accountInfo = [{
    model: 'fullName',
    placeholder: 'Full Name',
    ...

// some place with access to `user`
$scope.inputs = {
    fullName: user.fullName,
    email: user.email,
    ...
};

// html
<input ... ng-model="inputs[input.model]">
```

Since ng-model only accepts a reference, variations of this are essentially all you can reasonably do.

Comment: I changed by code to this,  but now it seems to have overwritten the placeholder in each input field [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/hewiK). Any way to fix this?

Comment: You've defined default values for ng-model on each input in your list `accountInfo`. These are overriding the placeholder. Try making the ng-model property null or `''` to start with in accountInfo, then the placeholders should appear.

Comment: how would I bind the ng-model then?

Comment: Look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZEigQ9I5xLNSg7tE2zdP?p=preview -- the ng-model will bind fine, and if it is empty you will see the placeholder.

Comment: i get that, but now I can't bind what I want to it. For example, user.fullName for the first input field. Chrome inspector tool shows that they all have the ng-model of input.model